# How can open spheres be shapes like squares?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm reading through Schaum's General Topology and I came across the section on equivalent metrics. So, the author introduces the idea that metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent when the $d-$open spheres of $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same topology on a space $X$. Then, as an example, the author goes on to show that the three metrics below all serve as a base for the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

So, I can clearly understand how we can use these shapes as a base for the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What I don't understand is how $S_{d_1}(p,\delta)$ and $S_{d_2}(p,\delta)$ are open "spheres". Geometrically speaking $S_{d_1}(p,\delta)$ and $S_{d_2}(p,\delta)$ are squares. Since they are squares, they are not "spheres" in the sense that they are sets centered at some point $p$ which contain all points within $\delta$ of $p$. Like I said, squares are perfectly fine as a base for the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but can we really call $S_{d_1}(p,\delta)$ and $S_{d_2}(p,\delta)$ open *spheres*? In a square centered at $p$, won't some points be farther from $p$ than others, thus violating our traditional notion of open sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spheres in metrics do not mean a physical sphere, i.e. a round circle or something like that.

In fact, usually, a sphere is an open neighborhood of a certain point that contains all points which have a distance to the center point lower than $\delta$. The key observation is that the "distance" is just a function (which has certain properties s.t. it's called "metric"), but it doesn't have to be the Euclidean distance.

You are imaging a circle - that is using the Euclidean distance as your metric. However, the square comes by using the metric $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \max\{|y_2-y_1|,|x_2-x_1|\}$. The shape of the set of all points with $d(x,y) < 1$ is indeed a square, which is, nevertheless, called the "sphere" around a point. That may seem confusing at first glance, but working with topology, spheres can have all kind of shapes, which could be non-circular as well.

In general open spheres, topologically speaking, are subsets in a metric space $(R,d)$ of the form $S_d(p,\delta) = \{q \in R| d(p,q)<\delta\}$, whereas closed spheres are $S_d(p,\delta) = \{q \in R| d(p,q)\leq\delta\}$.

In your case we have e.g. $R=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said, but looking at the example, if the author is saying that the class of open squares serves as a base for the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, don't we HAVE to assume that the distance is Euclidean distance?

Comment: The natural topology doesn't necessarily depend on the Euclidean distance, but you're correct that this metric does induce the natural topology.

However, you can create an open circle from the metric which forms squares by taking the union of infinitely many open squares.

Comment: That's where the difference between metric and topology can be seen: The single open sets differ, but the total topology does not. Taking the union of infinitely many open circles can give you a square and taking the union of infinitely many open squares can give you a circle. That's why it is a base of the natural topology, because each open circle can be represented by the (infinite) union of squares

Comment: I see. So, tell me if this is a correct assumption: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a base for the Euclidean topology, we can probably use whatever convex shape we want: squares, triangles, octagons, etc. since the arbitrary union of convex shapes can be used to approximate a circle. So at the level of the base, we have any convex shape we like, but those convex shapes have to make a circle in the end (for the Euclidean topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: Yeah, that seems  correct. You can imagine that you just need a somehow "small" surrounding of a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, how this looks like doesn't really matter.

Comment: @SunRoad Yes that is completely true, it doesnt even have to be convex. the interior of any polygon will work. You just need for the shape to satisfy two things: It needs to be open, and for every open ball you need to be able to place the shape inside the open ball so that it contains the center.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If it's not convex, say it has a "hole" on top, you won't be able to fill the "hole" while not filling the left top and right top side. You also need the property that you can get the full open ball by just taking the union of infinitely many shapes - this property is not given for some non-convex shapes...

Comment: We can discuss it in the math chat. I think it's true

Comment: Oh, I just saw how it could be possible even with non-convex shapes. As you can choose the shapes to be arbitrarily small and you can translate them to left/right and up/down, it should be possible. This is no proof, but intuitively I got the point. I now think it's true as well :)

Comment: Yes, I proved the following: Let $S$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Then the family of sets of the form $T(S)$ where $T$ is an affine transform form a basis for $\mathbb R^2$ with the euclidean topology.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 3):

The metric $S_{\delta_2}$ that gives the diamonds is sometimes called the Manhattan distance.

Consider a city in which the points are only the intersections of two streets. Assume that all the city blocks are perfect squares. Then the "distance" between two corners would be the manhattan distance.

So if you are currently located at corner $c$ then for every integer distance the set of corners at that distance will form that "diamond" (of course it won't have all of the points since there is only going to be a finite number of points).

So this is a way in which the "spheres" can come up in real life. But I think they are only "spheres" in the sense that they are the sets of points that are at a fixed distance from another "center" point.

[image]

Comment: That's really cool and I agree with how you brought up the Manhattan topology. That works precisely when the only points are the ones located at street intersections. But the author seems to be claiming that the open diamonds are "spheres" in $\mathbb{R}^2$, something which is geometrically impossible.

Comment: Seeing my answer that is possible if you interpret "spheres" not as circles, but as a set of points with a certain "distance", where this "distance" function can be different

Comment: @SunRoad The open diamonds aren't spheres in $\mathbb R^2$ with the euclidean topology. Although perhaps what the author is saying that these open squares can also serve as a "basis" for the euclidean topology. And in fact this is true, there is a very nice result that tells us that all norms for dimensional vector spaces are equivalent !

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you measure distance.

Let's write $x = (x_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ and $y = (y_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ for points in Cartesian $n$-dimensional space. If we define $d(x, y) = \sum_{i} |x_i - y_i|$, then "spheres" are the axis-oriented "octahedra" as in the right-hand diagram. This metric is induced by a vector space norm, the $1$-norm.

More generally, if $p \geq 1$ is real we define the "$p$-distance" by $d(x, y) = \bigl(\sum_{i} |x_{i} - y_{i}|^{p}\bigr)^{1/p} =: \|x - y\|_{p}$. This function satisfies the axioms of a metric (positve-definiteness, symmetry, and the triangle inequality), so is a mathematically consistent measure of distance.

If instead we define $d(x, y) = \max|x_i - y_i| =: \|x - y\|_{\infty}$, then "spheres" are axis-oriented cubes as in the middle diagram. Like the $p$-distance, this metric is induced by a vector space norm, often called the uniform norm (because of its relationship to "uniform convergence" if you've come across the term). The "$\infty$-norm" notation is reasonable, since $\|\ \|_{\infty} = \lim\limits_{p \to \infty}\|\ \|_{p}$.